# Json array delete objects which are match a specific key value part

Tags: python, arrays, json

I call(get method) of a Api and which will return List of objects as Json.

```
    import requests
    import json

    jwt ='yJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIwM2ExMjU5NC0zYz'
    url2 = "https://smqrapi/api/w5/warn/keys2/?skip=0&limit=10"
    payload2={}
    headers2 = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+jwt
   }
   response2 = requests.request("GET", url2, headers=headers2, data=payload2)
```

response of above request is as following,

```
{
    "skip": 0,
    "limit": 100,
    "total": 204,
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "order953-sup",
            "updatedAt": "2022-05-26T06:48:21.044474Z",
            "activationDate": "2022-05-26T06:48:21.044341Z",
            "state": "Active",
            "usage": "any",
        },
        {
            "name": "order958-old",
            "updatedAt": "2022-05-26T06:48:21.003159Z",
            "activationDate": "2022-05-26T06:48:20.977907Z",
            "state": "Active",
            "usage": "any",
            "aliases": [
                {
                    "alias": "order958-old",
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": 0
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "order959-sup",
            "updatedAt": "2022-05-26T06:41:14.803581Z",
            "activationDate": "2022-05-26T06:41:14.803453Z",
            "state": "Active",
            "usage": "any",
        },
```

There are several objects return. I need to delete the objects which are having "name" key at last "-sup" as it is. There will be a separate Api for Delete objects. I can pass "name" to that Delete api and do the task. But I have doubt how to get the names which are exactly having "anything-sup" in last part of "name" key. I hope regex will works here. But don't have exact idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [str.endswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith). It does exactly what you need without regular expressions.

Comment: response2 = requests.request("GET", url2, headers=headers2, data=payload2)
users = json.loads(response2.text)
for user in users["resources"]:
    print(user.name.endswith('sup')) , I tried this one this given me error on last print statement as AttributeError. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: The `user` loop variable is a `dict`, so to access the name it's `user["name"]`. Note that `endswith()` returns a `bool`, so I suggest using it in an `if` statement before printing the full name. E.g., `for user in users["resources"]: if user["name"].endswith("-sup"): print(user["name"])`